How to create percentage chart like this use LightweightCharts?
I want to create percentage chart like this use LightweightCharts
percentage chart
I create like this but it only show line without dot above like image:
private func setupUI() {
    let sourceSegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: SourceType.allCases.map { $0.title })
    sourceSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sourceValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(sourceSegmentedControl)
    sourceSegmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sourceSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            sourceSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sourceSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            sourceSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    sourceSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    
    let formatterSegmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: FormatterType.allCases.map { $0.title })
    formatterSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(formatterValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(formatterSegmentedControl)
    formatterSegmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            formatterSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            formatterSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sourceSegmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -8)
        ])
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            formatterSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            formatterSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sourceSegmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -8)
        ])
    }
    formatterSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    
    
    let options = ChartOptions(
        layout: LayoutOptions(background: .solid(color: "#000"), textColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"),
        rightPriceScale: VisiblePriceScaleOptions(borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"),
        timeScale: TimeScaleOptions(borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"),
        crosshair: CrosshairOptions(mode: .normal),
        grid: GridOptions(
            verticalLines: GridLineOptions(color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)"),
            horizontalLines: GridLineOptions(color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)")
        ),
        localization: LocalizationOptions(priceFormatter: .javaScript(FormatterType.allCases[0].formatterString))
    )
    let chart = LightweightCharts(options: options)
    view.addSubview(chart)
    chart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            chart.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            chart.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            chart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            chart.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: formatterSegmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -8)
        ])
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            chart.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            chart.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            chart.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            chart.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: formatterSegmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -8)
        ])
    }
    self.chart = chart
}

private func setupData() {
    let options = AreaSeriesOptions(
        lastValueVisible: true,
        topColor: "rgba(21, 101, 192, 0.5)",
        bottomColor: "rgba(21, 101, 192, 0.5)",
        lineColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)",
        lineWidth: .two,
        crosshairMarkerBorderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
        crosshairMarkerBackgroundColor: "rgba(100, 50, 20, 1)"
    )
    let series = chart.addAreaSeries(options: options)
    let data = [
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-19"), value: 72.35),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-22"), value: 72.57),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-23"), value: 72.10),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-24"), value: 70.54),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-25"), value: 69.96),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-26"), value: 70.40),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-29"), value: 71.45),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-30"), value: 72.87),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-10-31"), value: 73.61),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-01"), value: 73.12),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-02"), value: 72.27),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-05"), value: 73.12),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-06"), value: 73.31),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-07"), value: 75.08),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-08"), value: 75.48),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-09"), value: 74.86),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-12"), value: 74.69),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-13"), value: 74.61),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-14"), value: 74.09),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-15"), value: 74.84),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-16"), value: 76.06),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-19"), value: 76.35),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-20"), value: 74.78),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-21"), value: 74.79),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-23"), value: 74.67),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-26"), value: 75.44),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-27"), value: 76.34),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-28"), value: 77.23),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-29"), value: 77.91),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-11-30"), value: 79.34),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-03"), value: 79.22),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-04"), value: 78.21),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-06"), value: 78.37),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-07"), value: 76.72),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-10"), value: 77.42),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-11"), value: 77.11),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-12"), value: 78.01),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-13"), value: 79.01),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-14"), value: 76.48),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-17"), value: 75.23),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-18"), value: 74.33),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-19"), value: 73.77),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-20"), value: 73.49),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-21"), value: 72.90),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-24"), value: 71.15),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-26"), value: 74.00),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-27"), value: 75.38),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-28"), value: 75.37),
        AreaData(time: .string("2018-12-31"), value: 76.41),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-02"), value: 75.59),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-03"), value: 74.04),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-04"), value: 76.27),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-07"), value: 75.43),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-08"), value: 75.99),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-09"), value: 75.41),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-10"), value: 74.48),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-11"), value: 74.90),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-14"), value: 73.37),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-15"), value: 74.50),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-16"), value: 74.61),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-17"), value: 75.60),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-18"), value: 75.87),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-22"), value: 75.83),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-23"), value: 75.44),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-24"), value: 73.17),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-25"), value: 72.95),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-28"), value: 72.92),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-29"), value: 73.23),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-30"), value: 73.37),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-01-31"), value: 74.43),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-01"), value: 76.45),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-04"), value: 76.87),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-05"), value: 77.15),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-06"), value: 77.39),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-07"), value: 76.82),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-08"), value: 77.52),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-11"), value: 76.71),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-12"), value: 78.52),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-13"), value: 79.02),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-14"), value: 78.94),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-15"), value: 79.81),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-19"), value: 79.24),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-20"), value: 79.43),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-21"), value: 79.83),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-22"), value: 80.77),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-25"), value: 80.38),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-26"), value: 80.74),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-27"), value: 80.62),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-02-28"), value: 81.29),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-01"), value: 81.65),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-04"), value: 81.37),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-05"), value: 81.70),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-06"), value: 80.76),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-07"), value: 80.45),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-08"), value: 79.80),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-11"), value: 80.87),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-12"), value: 81.23),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-13"), value: 81.60),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-14"), value: 81.49),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-15"), value: 81.57),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-18"), value: 81.35),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-19"), value: 81.91),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-20"), value: 82.08),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-21"), value: 82.95),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-22"), value: 82.29),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-25"), value: 82.35),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-26"), value: 82.92),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-27"), value: 82.29),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-28"), value: 82.63),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-03-29"), value: 83.17),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-01"), value: 83.30),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-02"), value: 83.21),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-03"), value: 83.18),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-04"), value: 81.85),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-05"), value: 81.15),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-08"), value: 80.95),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-09"), value: 80.80),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-10"), value: 80.82),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-11"), value: 79.84),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-12"), value: 79.43),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-15"), value: 78.53),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-16"), value: 77.56),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-17"), value: 73.92),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-18"), value: 73.19),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-22"), value: 73.46),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-23"), value: 74.60),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-24"), value: 74.73),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-25"), value: 76.34),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-26"), value: 76.63),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-29"), value: 76.78),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-04-30"), value: 78.71),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-01"), value: 78.72),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-02"), value: 79.52),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-03"), value: 80.00),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-06"), value: 79.48),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-07"), value: 77.90),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-08"), value: 78.18),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-09"), value: 78.33),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-10"), value: 78.19),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-13"), value: 77.17),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-14"), value: 77.42),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-15"), value: 77.55),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-16"), value: 79.13),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-17"), value: 78.72),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-20"), value: 78.88),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-21"), value: 79.50),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-22"), value: 80.98),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-23"), value: 81.02),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-24"), value: 81.17),
        AreaData(time: .string("2019-05-28"), value: 81.10)
    ]
    series.setData(data: data)
    self.series = series
}

How to create chart like that use LightweightCharts?
which ChartOptions make dot above line like that? Any sample suggestion to create same chart like that also welcome?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
